# How to swap UIScrollViews?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview

Let's imagine that I have 2 UIScrollViews with different UIImageViews inside. When I trigger an action I would like the contents, parameters etc (besides the location) of the 2nd UIScrollView to be passed onto the 1st UIScrollView.

So, here's the code that I've come up with:

```
-(void) someAction {
UIScrollView * scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] init]; // create an intermediary scrollView
scroll = secondScroll; // here I intent to pass the content of secondScroll to scroll
scroll.frame = firstScroll.frame; // here I assign the frame of firstScroll to scroll
so that it doesn't take the frame of secondScroll;
firstScroll =scroll;  // and then pass all the contents of scroll to firstScroll;     
}
```

But when I execute that and trigger the action, the firstScroll seems to take the content of secondScroll, but secondScroll seems to be deleted. I need it to stay as is.

Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@jrtc27 Thanks for your answer. I think I've found a solution and it seems to accomplish what I'm looking for. But I'm not sure if it's the right way or not. Here's what I do:

```
- (void)someAction {
    [[firstScroll subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperView:);//here I sort of blank out the content of the firstScroll
    NSArray * array = [secondScroll subviews];//place all subview of the secondScroll in array
    int i = 0;
    int nrOfSubviews = [array count];
    for (i=0;i<nrOfSubviews;i++) { //appoint them one by one to firstScroll
        [firstScroll addSubview:[array objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void) someAction {
    UIScrollView * scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] init]; // create an intermediary scrollView
```

That's WRONG. You'll be leaking memory with it, since you're losing the pointer to that scroll view after assigning it to a different object. You'd better simply declare UIScrollView *scroll; for that purpose.

```
    scroll = secondScroll; // here I intent to pass the content of secondScroll to scroll
```

But that's not what happens. The scroll views don't magically copy themselves; if you assign one to another, you only assign the pointer.

```
    scroll.frame = firstScroll.frame; // here I assign the frame of firstScroll to scroll
    // so that it doesn't take the frame of secondScroll;
```

So, from now on, if you operate on `scroll`, it will effect secondScroll.

```
    firstScroll = scroll;  // and then pass all the contents of scroll to firstScroll;
```

And with this, you assign firstScroll to SecondScroll. So firstScroll will now essentially be secondScroll, losing it (leaking memory again and again) and having done nothing useful.

```
}
```

What on Earth are you trying to do with this?

Assuming you want to exchange the two views, you should do something like this instead:

```
BOOL firstScrollVisible = NO; // in -init or whatever

- (void) someAction
{
    if (fistScrollVisible)
        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:secondScroll];
    else
        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:firstScroll];
    firstScrollVisible = !firstScrollVisible;
}
```

Comment: Well, I'm a total newbie in this that's obvious. But, my goal was to copy all the contents (in my case some UIImageViews) and parameters (if it's hidden, userInteractionEnabled etc) of the secondScroll to the firstScroll. How can I accomplish that?

Comment: You'd have to manually set them, like secondScroll.hidden = firstScroll.hidden or secondScroll.imageView.image = firstScroll.imageView.image

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that doesn't seem to work. Because ScrollViews don't answer to .imageView

Comment: @H2CO3 I'm sorry but I don't quite get what is being done in your last example. As I understand it has something to do with what is Visible or not on the screen. But what I need to do is simply (not as simple as I thought) assign the contents of one scrollView to another, but the initial one should remain as is.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the following:

```
- (void)someAction {
    [firstScroll removeFromSuperview]; // So that we do not leave the old firstScroll as a subview
    firstScroll = [secondScroll copy]; // Makes a copy of secondScroll and stores it in firstScroll
    [self addSubview:firstScroll]; // Add the new firstScroll to the view
}
```

**Important Note(s):**
This code *will* leak memory, as `-copy` returns an object with a reference count of +1, but we do not release `firstScroll`. I *highly* suggest you make `firstScroll` and `secondScroll` into `nonatomic, retain` properties (`@property (nonatomic, retain) UIScrollView *firstScroll`). If you want more info on this, just ask. Furthermore, you will need to make sure that `firstScroll` and `secondScroll` are never garbage values when this code gets run (it will crash) - depending on when and how it is called you may be fine.

Comment: For some reason it doesn't go through. And the program crashes with signal: SIGABRT.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clone a UI element, you use `NSCoder` (just like the nib file loader does).

```
NSData *scrollViewData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self.firstScroll];
CGRect oldFrame = self.secondScroll.frame;
self.secondScroll = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:scrollViewData];
self.secondScroll.frame = oldFrame;
```

This serializes the `UIView` and all its subviews into an `NSData` and then creates a complete copy of those from the `NSData`.

Comment: That also, comes out with signal SIGABRT. This also happened for @jrtc27 's example. Maybe something is wrong in the way I created these UIScrollViews. Does it make a difference if they were created in IB and not programmatically?

Comment: If `secondScroll` is an IBOutlet, you should never set it like this. It's shouldn't cause a crash, but it's just a bad idea (very confusing in low memory situations). If `secondScroll` is always a copy of `firstScroll`, then create `secondScroll` programmatically. SIGABRT means an exception. Look in your console log for the message.

Comment: Yes, both firstScroll and secondScroll are outlets because I constantly need to change their contents, position etc. So, I'm guessing this method won't work for me.